# Passing Javascript generated variable as parameter to Craft function

Tags: javascript, twig

I have a `javascript` generated string called `latlongParam` and I want to pass it into a `twig` statement (`Craft CMS`). For example, if I write in my script:

```
<script>
...
var test = "{{craft.smartMap.lookupCoords('Dundas Street East Toronto ON M5B 2G9 Canada').lat}}" 
...
</script>
```

then test becomes "-79.3804367". However, I want to pass in latlongParam param as so :

```
var test = "{{craft.smartMap.lookupCoords(latlongParam).lat}}"
```

I have tried doing: `"{{craft.smartMap.lookupCoords('" + latlongParam + "').lat}}";`

But I keep getting the following error before the page even loads:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("lat") on a boolean variable ("")."
>   since

Due to the fact that `"{{craft.smartMap.lookupCoords('" + latlongParam + "')}}";` becomes an empty string for some reason and i end up with "".lat

Does anyone know how i can pass this `javascript` generated string inside of `lookupCoords()`?

Comment: Can't be done as twig is rendered server side. There is now way javascript could interact with twig. You would need to use ajax to pass the JS variables and get the desired output

Comment: I think i understand... So twig is rendered BEFORE my JS script which is why i get a value for "test" when i manually insert a string into the lookupCoords() function but i get an empty string if I try to do it DURING script execution. (Please correct me if Im wrong). In any case, how exactly can i get this to work with Ajax (or any other way)? An example would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time DarkBee.

Comment: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19999/can-a-js-string-variable-be-used-in-twig/20000#20000

Comment: Great! Thank you.